# Getting CSS Buttons to Turn Green on Click and REMAIN GREEN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a project where I have to do some front-end work for a webpage. I have buttons that need to be clicked and turned a certain color and remain that same color after being clicked.

Below is my **CSS `<style>`** for the specific buttons:

```css
.button {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #3e1313;

    color: #3e1313;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
}

button:hover{background-color:orange;}

.button4 {border-radius: 10px;}
```

**HyperText**:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="columnExpand">
    <label class="container" name="lblDriverExperience">
      Driver Experience
      <input type="checkbox" name="chkDriverExperience" 
             onchange="divToggle('divDriver')">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="columnOption" id="divDriver">
    <button class="button button4">Good</button>
    <button class="button button4">Fair</button>
    <button class="button button4">Poor</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#test").click(function() {$(this).toggleClass( "active")})
</script>
```

Again, the button turns brown on hover, but I want it to turn green on click and remain green. There have been tons of questions but none have actually got me to the answer.

Comment: I don't actually see anywhere in your code where you've defined the clicked button colour as green. As caiovisk said below you should add some CSS to your active buttons.

Comment: divToggle Function is not defined

Answer (score 2):

You can toggle a class `.active` on your `button`

```
$(".columnOption .button").click(
  function() {$(this).toggleClass( "active")}
)
```

```js
$(".columnOption .button").click(
  function() {$(this).toggleClass( "active")}
)
```

```css
.button {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #3e1313;

    color: #3e1313;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;

    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 4px 2px;
}

button:hover{background-color:orange;}

.button4 {border-radius: 10px;}

.columnOption .button.active {
    background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="columnExpand">
    <label class="container" name="lblDriverExperience">
      Driver Experience
      <input type="checkbox" name="chkDriverExperience" 
             onchange="divToggle('divDriver')">
      <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <div class="columnOption" id="divDriver">
    <button class="button button4">Good</button>
    <button class="button button4">Fair</button>
    <button class="button button4">Poor</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working, it turns green for a fraction of a second but does not stay

Comment: @JClark It works for me. What browser are you using?

Answer (score 1):

This may be too simple for what you're looking for, but it works for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( ".button" ).click(function() { $( this ).css( "background-color", "green" )} );
</script>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/CriticalError/jLst5owk/

Answer (score 0):

```css
div label input {
   margin-right:100px;
}
body {
    font-family:sans-serif;
}

#ck-button {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#EFEFEF;
    border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

#ck-button label {
    float:left;
    width:4.0em;
}

#ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#911;
    color:#fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="ck-button">
   <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>red</span>
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: This is actually a checkbox that will look like a button, hope it works on all the browsers.